# Angularjs, why this service is executed automatically?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The following code is expected to trigger the 'ei' alert only after the user makes the click, but it is not the case. The alert appears at the begining. Why? And how to solve it? I'm not following the logic here (remarking my newcomer status)

Check it at http://jsfiddle.net/yDhv8/4/

html

```
<div ng-controller='StartAnalysis' ng-click="Process()">
{{status}} CLICK HERE TO START PROCESSING
</div>
```

js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

angular.module('myApp').controller('StartAnalysis', 
['$scope', 'Erase_added_panels', function ($scope, Erase_added_panels) {

$scope.status = 'waiting files ...';

$scope.Process = function() {
    alert('mm')
    Erase_added_panels;
    $scope.status = 'starting process ...';
    return false;
}
}]);

angular.module('myApp').factory('Erase_added_panels', function() {
    alert('ei')
    return true;
});
```

Cheers,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are declaring a factory, so this is a singleton that is executed:

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('Erase_added_panels', function() {
    alert('ei')
    return true;
});
```

If you want to trigger the alert later just return an object with a method doing what you need it to do:

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('Erase_added_panels', function() {
    return {
        foo: function () {
            alert('ei')
            return true;
        }
    };
});
```

And to call it

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('BarController', ['Erase_added_panels', function (Erase_added_panels) {
    Erase_added_panels.foo();
}]);
```

**NOTE:**

Angular specifies that a service is executed **as soon as** you require it somewhere in your application, here, it means **the simple fact of adding it as a dependency makes it executed.**

### Angular says ([as stated here](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.creating_services)):

> All services in Angular are instantiated lazily. This means that a
>   service will be created only when it is needed for instantiation of a
>   service or an application component that depends on it. In other
>   words, Angular won't instantiate services unless they are requested
>   directly or indirectly by the application.

Comment: Thanks, both of you are saying the same so I choose the first. One question to confirm I'm getting it: If I define a variable with the return (I return that variable), then the variable is not defined until I call the factory right? Without the return, the code is executed. Am I correct?

Comment: I updated my answer, because it would be too long in a comment

Answer (score 1):

The function you provide to the factory method gets executed once when your application loads (services are singletons).

so this code:

```
alert('ei')
    return true;
```

gets executed during initialisation in order **create your service**.
So from this function, you should **return an object** to work with in your controller:

If you want to alert something from within a service, you should return an object:

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('Erase_added_panels', function() {  
    return {
     alertUser : function(){
         alert('hey!');        
     };
});
```

Then from your controller, you can use the object you just returned to call its methods:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('StartAnalysis', 
['$scope', 'Erase_added_panels', function ($scope, Erase_added_panels) {

    $scope.status = 'waiting files ...';

    $scope.Process = function() {
        Erase_added_panels.alertUser();
    }
}]);
```

please read the documentation as well: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.creating_services

Comment: I already checked the guide, but prior to these 2 answers I found it ofuscated. Then again, thanks for clarifying, I am starting to feel more confortable :)